# Installing extensions into Selenium Grid (remote driver) under local Python 3 to a remote server running under docker

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have changed the title of this post to make it easier to find, and have solved the issue. See my answer below.

OLD TITLE -  Selenium Grid 4.0.0.Beta-1 Docker driver crashes my python app when adding chrome extensions when Selenium local does not

I have hunted high and low for a recent answer and tried most of the older ones (so please do not mark this is as duplicate) and every site that google presented me ..nothing works so far. I want to use the latest version of Selenium Grid (Docker image) , I have it set up and working, and I can scrape data remotely as long as I do not have an extension installed or define a user directory, as follows...

This code does work, but it runs on a local browser and not on the docker Selenium Grid.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class sgrid:    
       
    def init_chrome_with_cookies_local(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\python\vidiqext\3.41.0_0.crx')
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/charl/OneDrive/python/userdata") 
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) 
        return driver
```

But when I switch to this

```
    def init_chrome_with_cookies_remote(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\python\vidiqext\3.41.0_0.crx')
        chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:/Users/charl/OneDrive/python/userdata')
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub',options=chrome_options)
        return driver
```

....it crashes, and it does not matter if both the add_extension and add_argument are tried, or one then the other, they both cause the app to crash.

File "c:/Users/charl/OneDrive/python/sgrid.py", line 183, in iterate
driver.get('about:blank')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment
PS C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\dataharvest\visualstudio>

This error really just means the driver did not get configured properly as all the other code is the same.  Now I understand that some solutions on StackOverflow  use the DesiredCapabilities way, but I am told that this is deprecated, and none have worked either so if anyone has this working in Python 3, Selenium Grid 4 on docker, I would be so grateful to know.

EDIT: It might be worth noting that my local machine is Windows Anaconda and my Remote machine is Debian running Docker, they are not on the same machine. Do I need to stipulate the paths to these files/directories on the local or remote machines?

EDIT 2: The path to either the crx file or the user-data-dir should be local to the remote machine, I have worked out, which is /dev/shm in my case which must be available both inside and outside the docker container, and not the local machine. It still crashes but after adding user data remotely, so part of the solution is now found. This is not obvious as the command driver.save_screenshot(...) for instance saves files locally.

Under this scenario

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/dev/shm/vidiq")
```

seems to work (files are created by chrome normally, and it does not crash, and scrapes blank data because there is no VidIQ extension), but ...

```
chrome_options.add_extension('/dev/shm/3.41.0_0.crx')
```

crashes the driver immediately. I checked remote permissions, 777 and 666 respectively.

Edit 3: Can confirm that the crx file and user data should have a remote path, But still no joy in spinning up a remote Selenium Grid with an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's just clarify on the setup. My Windows laptop is running Python 3 (using Anaconda) and all application code is local. My Selenium Grid is running a VM in the cloud under docker where I have Selenium Grid, Portainer (to manage docker) and incidentally mongdb to save scraped results. All is now working.

The objective, to install extensions onto the remote Selenium Grid, which by its nature has no way to directly interact with chrome. So you cannot just pause the script, add the extension manually, and carry on. Oftentimes we run chrome almost blind.

Here are a couple of methods that did not work for me.

1. Training Selenium to add the extension by keypresses using for instance send.keys. This won't work because the very last popup before installing the extension has buttons "Do you want to install the extension" and "Cancel". This popup comes from the interaction between chrome.exe and Windows and is not automatable from chromedriver. It is in the local Windows GUI, not the DOM of the webpage.
2. Creating a userdata profile locally, interacting with chrome to install the extension, and copying that profile to the remote machine. Chromedriver/Selenium will use the profile, but it won't bring up the extensions.
3. Installing extensions using a crx file, the most commonly quoted method, does not seem to work when applied to a Selenium Grid running remotely. It crashes.

The documentation is unclear to me whether the paths to userdata and the extensions should be on the local python machine or the remote Selenium machine. While oddly there are  Exceptions that refer to the keys being wrong when the path of the extension is local, the answer is that both should be remote.

Since I am running under docker we need a path that I can upload files to and that are also available to the container inside docker. By going into portainer and examining the drives bound to that container, I was able to determine that that drive was dev/shm/ and that both the container and my SSH connection would refer to it by the same path(not always the case in docker). The dev folder is in the root of my debian/docker setup.

So this worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/dev/shm/vidiqa")
unpacked_extension_path = '/dev/shm/vidiqa/Default/Extensions/pachckjkecffpdphbpmfolblodfkgbhl/3.43.1_0'
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(unpacked_extension_path))
#chrome_options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub', options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("chrome://extensions")
driver.save_screenshot('sdriver.png')
print('driver loaded sucessfully')
```

However, there are a few more steps required. You will note that we are not using the normal crx

```
chrome_options.add_extension(path/to/remote/extension/ext.crx)
```

but the unpacked folder  method

```
        unpacked_extension_path = '/dev/shm/vidiqa/Default/Extensions/pachckjkecffpdphbpmfolblodfkgbhl/3.43.1_0'
        chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(unpacked_extension_path))
```

To get this folder and contents, identify the folder in a local userdata profile and find and copy the folder. The folder for me was here....

```
C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\python\newuserdata\Default\Extensions\pachckjkecffpdphbpmfolblodfkgbhl
```

...because that is where I chose to put it when I ran Selenium using this

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/charl/OneDrive/python/newuserdata")
```

But there are other ways. The point is that it comes from userdata that you have locally installed your plugin into, in my case by pausing the running with a time.sleep(120) line and installing it manually.

You then need to copy the entire contents of this to your remote server. Now the first time you run the code above, Selenium will create the folder on the remote drive under...

```
dev/shm/your_directory_name_for_the_userdata
```

...and it will populate it will about 50meg or more of data. Nothing should crash but it will not load the extension. So run it once to populate the userdata, and SSH into the remote directory and post the directory you copied above into

```
/dev/shm/your_directory_name_for_the_userdata/Default/Extensions/
```

You will need to create the Extensions folder. All this makes much more sense when you study the lines....

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/dev/shm/vidiqa")
unpacked_extension_path = '/dev/shm/vidiqa/Default/Extensions/pachckjkecffpdphbpmfolblodfkgbhl/3.43.1_0'
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(unpacked_extension_path))
```

And work out what we are doing.

1. Creating a folder remotely to save the userdata into
2. Copying the extension (first-time run)  into the Extensions folder, something that would have been done automatically had you installed the extension manually.
3. Load the extension.

So the trick is you need to manually copy the Extension to the userdata.

The load-extension code must be run each time you want the extension loaded, it does not remember it the way it does when you install it manually. Though if the extension needs logging into, which mine did, this can be done using selenium and that cookie is remembered on subsequent loadings of the driver.My code offers a quick screenshot to check it is working which is saved locally to the location of your python.

Hope all this will save the 10 days of struggling it took me to figure all this out. Selenium Grid is worth it BTW, it scales up the number of simultaneous drivers running automatically depending on the machine it is running on, one for each core processor.

Comment: Thanks, I found this helpful. I was wondering why add_extension wasn't working. You're 10 days of work is appreciated :) 